# How can I fix this error in my Java game?

Tags: java

I have a little bit of programming experience in web development languages such as HTML, CSS, JQuery, JavaScript, PHP, Python etc., but I am no taking an AP Computer Science class at school to learn Java. To see how similar it is to other languages in both syntax and how to go about different problems I decided to make a simple blackjack game that i have made in other languages before.

I have run into and error where I want to check to see what the user has input, and if it is a certain character, output different things such as a help sentence, welcome message, or just simply start or stop the game. For some reason it reads the input and I can log it to the console but it will not run the methods that I have created and called in the if statement inside the while loop. I am going to post the whole script since I have only been programming in Java for 2 weeks or so now and have no idea where my error could be.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class testClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
    // Creates a scanner to get input from the keyboard

    boolean gameStart = false;
    // starts false, turns true when 'B' is input

    welcome();
    //displays the welcome message

    while (true) {
        // loop to play the game

        String input = kbd.nextLine().toUpperCase();
        // gets the next input from the user

        if (input == "B") {
            // checks the users input

            gameStart = true;
            // 'turns on' the game

            double[] hand = drawCards();
            // makes an array of 2 cards
            System.out.print(input); //REMOVE

        } else if (input == "?") {
            // checks the users input

            help(gameStart);
            // displays the help message depending on if the game has started or not
            System.out.print(input); //REMOVE

        } else if (input == "Q") {
            // checks the users input

            System.out.print(input); // REMOVE
            break;
            // ends the game loop

        } // ends if

    } // ends while


} // end main

public static void welcome() {
    // displays the welcome message

    System.out.printf("Welcome to blackjack! %nEnter 'B' to begin. %nEnter '?' at any time to see help %nEnter 'Q' at any time to quit %n => ");
    // the welcome message

}

public static void help(boolean gameStart) {
    //displays the help message

    if (gameStart) {

        System.out.printf("Enter '?' at any time to see help %nEnter 'Q' at any time to quit %nEnter 'H' to hit %nEnter 'S' to stay %n => ");
        // the help message when the game has already started

    } else {

        System.out.printf("Welcome to blackjack! %nEnter 'B' to begin. %nEnter '?' at any time to see help %nEnter 'Q' at any time to quit %nEnter 'H' to hit %nEnter 'S' to stay %n => ");
        // the help message when the game hasn't started

    }

} //  end help

public static double randCard() {
    // creates a random card

    double card = Math.round(Math.random() * 10);
    // number 1-10

    if (card == 10 || card == 0) {
        // no cards at 10 or 0

        double x = Math.round(Math.random() * 10);
        // variable used to choose J Q K or A when card is 0 or 10

        if (x < 3) {
            // Jack
            card = 11;
        } else if (x < 5) {
            // Queen
            card = 12;
        } else if (x < 7) {
            // King
            card = 13;
        } else {
            // Ace
            card = 10;
        } 

    }

    return card;
    // returns a single card

} // end randCard

public static double[] drawCards() {
    //creates 2 random cards and returns an array

    double card1 = randCard();
    double card2 = randCard();
    // stores the 2 random cards in variables

    double[] cards = {card1, card2};
    // places the 2 random cards in an array

    return cards;
    // returns the array of cards

} // end drawCards

} // end class
```

Comment: Also note that usually, class name starts with an uppercase letter, and [beware](http://floating-point-gui.de/) when using `==` for double

Comment: change this `(input == "B")` with `(input.equals("B"))`.

Comment: you can also try like this ("B".equals(input)) .

Comment: All I can say to this is that there is a reason Java is object-oriented ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are list of things you need to correct:

- As per [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) it's recommended to have class names starting with First letter as caps - Camel Case convention
- String comparison should be done via `equals()` and not '**==**' that compares references.

  That means that, change the occurrences of:

  - `input == "B"` to `input.equals("B")`
  - `input == "?"` to `input.equals("?")`
  - `input == "Q"` to `input.equals("Q")`

Be aware that if the `input`is `null`, it will result in NullPointerException. Better practice would be to use `"B".equals(input)` in that case. Looks like these are already answered as part of comments as well.

**P.S** : I can't say that your program will work correct after this change, But correction of these should help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `equals()` method of string instead of `==`. Hope that helps.